# how to verify this time/date string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, datetime, verify

I have a string in the format of:

3:00 pm on Aug 28

What would be the best way to verify that a valid time and valid date is contained within this string? My first thought was to split the string and use two regexs to match a time and the other one to match that specfic date format (abbreviate month day). However I'm having a little bit of trouble with the second regex (the one for the specfic date format). How else could one go about verifying the string is in the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public boolean isValid( String dateStr ) {

    //    K: hour of the day in am/pm
    //    m: minute of a hour
    // 'on': static text
    //  MMM: name of the month with tree letters
    //   dd: day of the month (you can use just d too)
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( "K:m a 'on' MMM dd", Locale.US );

    try {
        df.parse( dateStr );
        return true;
    } catch ( ParseException exc ) {
    }

    return false;

}
```

More about the format string here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  Use a format string something like `HH:mm aa 'on' MMM dd`.

You may have to add `yyyy` to the format string and `2012` to your input.

Comment: I think he's trying to check if a pre-existing string is valid as opposed to create a new date-string. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just call `parse()` with your string, it will throw a `ParseException` if it doesn't fit the format.  You get the returned `Date` for free!  You might want to set `isLenient` to `false`.  Use the 2-argument form of `parse` if you want to make sure the whole input string was used.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and make sure it doesn't use [lenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) parsing:

```
try {
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a 'on' MMM dd", Locale.US);
  df.setLenient(false);
  Date dt = df.parse(s);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
  // Wrong format
}
```

Comment: Sorry João, I didn't see your answer.