# How to retrieve Date from JSONObject

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I retrieve a java.util.Date from a [Google Gson JSONObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)?

```
{ ..., "date":"2012-12-21 00:58:06.0, ...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date  = formatter.parse(object.getString("date");
```

Answer (score 1):

The section here about dealing with dates might help: https://github.com/upgradingdave/javajing/tree/master/json-using-gson

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it directly. You will need to parse this date (String) to create an java.util.Date. Take a look here: [how to verify this time/date string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168668/how-to-verify-this-time-date-string-in-java/12168765#12168765)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
Date date = gson.fromJson(json, Date.class);
//Where gson = new Gson();
```